# Optaplanner: discrepancy between bestScore and score of bestSolution

Tags: java, optaplanner

I observed that the solver.bestScore is not always the same as the calculated score of the solver.bestSolution. Any idea why?
I also have another issue, possibly related: the score of the current best solution at the time I persist the planning entities in my db is very different (and far better) the the score I obtain when I reload the planning entities and resume the optimisation. Any idea why?

Thanks.
JLL

Answer (score 0):

Smells like score corruption. Run it again with `<environmentMode>FULL_ASSERT</>` or `FAST_ASSERT`, for a much longer time.

That should give a helpful error message. Turn on `DEBUG` or even `TRACE` logging for `org.optaplanner` to help diagnose the problem.

If you're using `<moveThreadCount>`, reproduce it first with it off. If there really is no way to reproduce it without it, even after 30 runs on 10 different datasets, it might be a cloning issue, which means you're missing a `@DeepPlanningClone` somewhere. Otherwise, it's a score corruption and the `FULL_ASSERT` will help pinpoint it.

Comment: Actually, I see an error in DEBUG logs. I understand it refers to one of my rules but do you have any clue about what I should check in the rule? Here's a portio of the log. oops , the log is too long.

Comment: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The move thread with moveThreadIndex (0) has thrown an exception. Relayed here in the parent thread.
        at org.optaplanner.core.impl.heuristic.thread.OrderByMoveIndexBlockingQueue.take(OrderByMoveIndexBlockingQueue.java:142)

Comment: ..... at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The constraintMatchTotal (org.optaplanner.examples.pharmacyrostering.solver/MaxOneDutyInInclusionZone=-801000hard/0medium/0soft) could not remove constraintMatch (org.optaplanner.examples.pharmacyrostering.solver/MaxOneDutyInInclusionZone/

Comment: ......at org.optaplanner.core.api.score.constraint.ConstraintMatchTotal.removeConstraintMatch(ConstraintMatchTotal.java:141)